# TexMaker does not generate pdf (no error)

Tags: miktex, texmaker, windows

I was writing a document for months using TexMaker and everything worked fine. Today suddenly nothing (usefull) happened after quick build. I also tried pdfLatex and Latex commands and log file doesn't contain any error.

When I click pdflatex command it starts and ends doing something in a second and the log file contains the following content:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.11.25) 29 MAY 2016 21:18
entering extended mode
**test.tex
(E:\Dropbox\MAGISTRSKA\LATEX\test\test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
```

The log file is the same for any latex document. For long document that I'm writing it for months as well as for document looking like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

I'm using windows 8.1 and since yesterday(when everything was working) I didn't install any programs or change latex configuration. But I did get bluescreen today.

Any suggestions what I could do to fix that?

Comment: try to use TeXstudio http://www.texstudio.org/

Comment: Run your test document on a command line to get a better error message (and make a backup in case something is really wrong on your pc)

Comment: Do you an reboot?  Then ther was a change!  BTW: Your MiKTeX version is outdated! The current version is `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)`, yours is `-1.40.13`! Can you please explain better your problem?  Do you have a deadline? Can you update?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".