# TexMaker not working

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texmaker

I've been using LaTeX for some years now, and I've never really had a problem. However, since two days ago, I have not been able to generate PDFs using TeXmaker.

The problem started after I used MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin) to install a package that LaTeX couldn't find. After that, when I run any of my previous `.tex`-files (that I'm certain worked fine), only a `.log`-file was generated but no PDF (just as this other guy: [TexMaker does not generate pdf (no error)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312110/texmaker-does-not-generate-pdf-no-error))

Since then, I've uninstalled MiKTeX and TeXmaker and re-installed them, and the problem remains. For example, when I run this simple test:

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \begin{document}
    Test
    \end{document}
```

I get no `.pdf`-file and only this `.log`-file at the bottom:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.6.28) 28 JUN 2016 17:02
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 1
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
[1
{C:/Users/Magdalena Bennett/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(test.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
202 strings out of 493335
2066 string characters out of 3139222
53225 words of memory out of 3000000
3817 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
23i,4n,17p,114b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.p
fb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 11248 bytes).
PDF statistics:
10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Any help would be really appreciate it, because now I'm really stuck and I need to keep working. Thanks!

Comment: What about the `Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 11248 bytes).` line? Maybe the file ended up somewhere else?

Comment: The log says that the pdf has been created. Why do you believe that is not there?

Comment: Thanks for this. The pdf was not created (at least in the same folder where I tested it). I now re-installed MiKTeX again and at least now is generating the pdfs, though I still have no idea what happened there.

Comment: When I taught LaTeX to college math students I would see this fairly often and the solution I taught to the students was to 1)Before an installation of Miktex followed by TexMaker, first to a complete shutdown and reboot. 2) Complete the installation.  3) Then follow the installation with another complete shutdown and reboot.     Over time I learned this was overkill and  usually not needed.  However some other programs leave the operating system 'confused' and this is reflected in the LaTeX installation.

Comment: uhm: have you updated the FNDB after you installed the new packages?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by reinstalling MikTeX.